# How to Center Button In Tailwind in a div

Tags: tailwind-css

How do you center a button in tailwind in a div?

I have tried:

1. justify-center
2. items-center
3. mx-auto
4. content-center

In all cases, the button is stuck on the left hand side.
​​​​​
The h2 and p center no problem.

```
<div class="container py-10 px-10 mx-0 min-w-full" className="contactdiv">
  <h2 class="text-5xl text-white text-center">Contact Us</h2>

  <br />
  <p class="text-center text-white">Kickstart your career in BioPharma with the Mendeleev Institute right now</p>
  <button class="bg-purple-900 text-white hover:bg-blue-400 font-bold py-2 px-4 mt-3 rounded items-center">Learn More</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

I suggest to use `flex flex-col items-center` on the container to center children across the y axis.

```html
<div class="container py-10 px-10 mx-0 min-w-full flex flex-col items-center">
  <h2 class="text-5xl mb-3 text-black">Contact Us</h2>
  <p class="text-black">Kickstart your career in BioPharma with the Mendeleev Institute right now</p>
  <button class="bg-purple-900 text-white hover:bg-blue-400 font-bold py-2 px-4 mt-3 rounded">Learn More</button>
</div>
```

Here is the [result on Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/uajRvfhLIr)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I also managed to solve it - will post solution above

Comment: Solution doesn't work - have encountered same problem now multiple times - have posted correct solution below.

Comment: This actually did work for me. I had had a div with the suggested classnames and a single button inside. `<div class='flex flex-col items-center'><button>Centered</button></div>`

Answer (score 2):

I used css grid on my solution. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container py-10 px-10 mx-0 min-w-full grid place-items-center" className="contactdiv">
    <h2 class="text-5xl text-black text-center">Contact Us</h2>
  
    <br />
    <p class="text-center text-black">Kickstart your career in BioPharma with the Mendeleev Institute right now</p>
    <button class="bg-purple-900 text-white hover:bg-blue-400 font-bold py-2 px-4 mt-3 rounded items-center">Learn More</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `flex flex-col items-center justify-center` in the parent `div`.

```
<div class="authButtons basis-1/4 border-4 flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
  <button class="font-fa text-3xl border-2">Hey!</button>
</div>
```

You can check it out in this [tailwind demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/40BgPxt7xP).

Answer (score 1):

Correction - Having encountered this problem multiple times - NONE of the solutions posted worked.

Adding flex, flex-col and items-center to the parent component does nothing.

The only thing that works for me, is to wrap the button in `<p className="text-center"></p>` tags, only then the button is centered.

Comment: I have the same issue but your reply here has left me confused. What kind of tag did you warp the button in? what classe/s did you use to center the button? I think you mean to imply that you added the centering class to the tag?

Comment: It won't let me submit a proposed edit since I only wanted to add two backticks, but the invisible HTML in the above answer is `<p className="text-center"></p>`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the button in a flex container and justify content to the center. Since the button is the only element in its container

```html
<div class="container py-10 px-10 mx-0 min-w-full">
  <h2 class="text-5xl text-white text-center">Contact Us</h2>

  <br />
  <p class="text-center text-white">Kickstart your career in BioPharma with the Mendeleev Institute right now</p>
  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <button class="bg-purple-900 text-white hover:bg-blue-400 font-bold py-2 px-4 mt-3 rounded items-center">Learn More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use canter tag of html.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

simplest way using flex:

```
<div class="px-12 py-12 space-x-2 flex justify-center">
        <a href="" class="py-3 px-3 rounded bg-green-600 text-white font-bold text-2xl hover:bg-green-700">Add X</a>
        <a href="" class="py-3 px-3 rounded bg-green-600 text-white font-bold text-2xl hover:bg-green-700">Add Y</a>
        <a href="" class="py-3 px-3 rounded bg-green-600 text-white font-bold text-2xl hover:bg-green-700">Add Z</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used 'justify-center'.

Ex:

```
<div class="flex justify-center">
  <button></button>
</div>
```